# Two columns form bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm not so good with bootstrap so please give me a hand. I want to have a page designed with bootstrap divided into two two columns. First column of size 'col-md-4' should contain a some text information and the second column of size 'col-md-8' to contain the actual form.

I tried something but doesn't work.

```
<section>
 <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
 <h3>EVENT INFORMATION</h3>
  <small>Add some information about this section</small>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8 form-group">
  <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
  <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input"> 
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/62s24kmp/

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Your jsfiddle example doesn't do anything cause you haven't linked bootstrap CSS (External Links section is empty)

Comment: Bootply includes Bootstrap automatically: https://www.bootply.com/BxpZIgyWOI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap yours `<div class="col-md-*">` with a `<div class="row">`
Don't forget to add external ressources when you provide a jsfiddle.

Here the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d0nm6nog/)

[image]